# Can forms authentication restrict any path?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, webforms

Our client has a virtual file server setup which contains some PDF's he wanted to restrict.  He thought they would be restricted from non-logged in users, however they've somehow turned up in google search results.

So my question is, if I setup forms authentication (he currently doesn't have any authentication) on his website, can I restrict access to any directory I want?  For example, the path of the PDF's is on another server, mapped to the "S" drive like this:
S:\Files\PDFs\

Can I list this path somewhere in a config file to restrict it to only authenticated users?

Thanks

Comment: Look at [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) to stop it from getting indexed by search engines. BTW if you don't have restriction on your virtual file server, it will not make any difference. You might be having reference to VFS from elsewhere, hence search engine has indexed it.

Comment: check the answer and apply settting accroding to it in you config will work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put this kind of web.config in the folder where pdf files are located , this will not allow unauthnicated user to access you files

```
<location path="FolderNameAuthenticationNeed" allowOverride="true">
<system.web>

<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>

</authorization> </system.web>
</location>
```